# What does autoresize = RM+BM mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, autolayout

I get this when using the Xcode debugging console with this line:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

Then I get back lines with the recursive description like this

```
<UILabel: 0xb0b8170; frame = (138 106; 200 15); text = 'Distance'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb0b8220>>
```

What does "autoresize = RM+BM" and is there a place I can lookup the meaning of the letters? I also saw something like this "autoresize = LM+W+RM+TM+H+BM".

Comment: Probably: Left, Right, Top, Bottom, Margin, Width (flexible), Height (flexible)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

autoresize indicates which bits have been set in the autoresizingMask:

```
RM = UIAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
BM = UIAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
```

The others follow a similar abbreviation syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you give all the constraints, then you can easily see all of them. These all indicates the UIAutoResizing.

RM means Right margin

BM means Bottom margin

W means Width

H means Height

LM means Left margin

TM means Top margin

Answer (score -2):

```
<SIGMAPOINT_MPAdView: 0x10db888a0; frame = (0 0; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = LM+RM; layer = <CALayer: 0x282b704c0>>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.